# Real-time collaborative rich text editing

Tags: javascript, node.js, editor, real-time, collaborative

I would like to have a real-time collaborative rich text editor for my webapp. So far i've done a LOT of research and i'm really a bit frustrated that there is nothing fitting out there.
The thing is, that every solution out there is tightly coupled to an editor (Firepad for example uses CodeMirror/ Etherpad uses Etherpad).
There are only two other solutions i found interesting:

- ShareJs -> works only for plain text
- Webstrate -> This was the MOST promising to me. It can handle DOM synchronization and therefore it can handle every contenteditable - great!

But the problem with Webstrate is, that it is in an alpha Version. So for me it was too buggy - didn't work out. Tried to get it working for about 2 days. The text synchronization was easy. But it didn't work with iframes or other stuff.

My claims are pretty high for a collaborative RTE - it should support:

- Images
- Iframes
- Video
- Text (of course)

While i'm searching for about 3-4 days now for a solution - maybe someone of you has a hint? Would be very gentle ;)

Comment: I'm sorry that it's not helpful comment to you. But, what about checking [Google Wave](https://code.google.com/p/wave-protocol/source/browse/)'s repo? AFAIR Google Wave supported such rich usages.

Comment: Thanks for your comment ;) I think Google Wave is now part of the Apache family. And so far they couldn't manage to release a stable version - only nightly builds (not so promising). But I'd recommend you all to check out Webstrates. It works amazing and if we work together there we can improve it. My problem was for example with Google Maps - that couldn't be synced. But i implemented an option so that some divs are not synced and  instead get rendered by the clients -> works like charm.

Comment: I'm sorry. I thought you want to implement such editor and find projects to do a benchmarking. (I did that long time ago) Well, for production use... if you failed to find one that suits your taste exactly, I think it's better to contribute to some stable project supporting plug-in for you to add functionality you want than to improve some other's alpha-stage work (it's exciting but takes so much time). Doesn't Etherpad support plugin concept?

Comment: Etherpad was one of the most promising. But it is really HUGE!! And since it is not necessary for me to have a 100% waterproofed solution, i took Webstrates. Also Webstrates is using ShareJS (written by an ex Google Waver) and the initial commit was 3 years ago - as i just found out :)
It seems pretty stable when you have figured out once how to do it. I tested it with 4 person writing and inserting images/text and stuff and it works.

I also think, that webstrates is a much smarter way then Etherpad (so far i see no disadvantages) because it syncs the dom. So it is plugable to every editor.

Comment: I agree Etherpad is so huge. Anyway I think you already found the one that suits your taste well :) So happy coding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try http://swellrt.org, is a complete framework to develop real-time collaborative apps including **rich-text** support and an **editor** for Web.

It provides a JS API, analogue to GD Real-time API, plus rich-text editting.

The editor can be extended to support any attachment.

It's a fork of [Apache Wave](https://incubator.apache.org/wave/) that generalizes the original code.

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing I found is http://quilljs.com/ - it has an API for getting and updating text deltas and also for getting and setting multiple labeled cursors. It doesn't manage the real-time editing for you, but it gives you enough to work with (more than any other project I found). However it is not as comprehensive as other editors in formatting (for example, it doesn't support tables and nested lists). It is somewhat extensible, so you may be able to add support for additional HTML elements.

Answer (score 1):

Robust collaborative rich text editors are still somewhat bleeding edge. Most web based text editors fall into of two categories.

1. Those that are compatible with real time collaboration but have fairly limited functionality (e.g. no tables, no nested elements, etc.).
2. Those that are very robust web based rich text editors, but lack that API to integrate with real time technologies.

Then there are the collaboration engines like ShareDB, Google Drive Realtime API, SwellRT, and [Convergence](https://convergence.io) (full disclosure I am a founder at [Convergence Labs](https://convergencelabs.com)). These types of systems each have their own opinion on data models and how to mediate collaboration. It may be the case that the way your favorite rich text editor works internally is incompatible with the API of the collaboration engine.

The technologies out there that simply sync the DOM are interesting because they are often portable across editors and are less dependent on the editor API, but they tend to lack a lot of the required real time editing capabilities that are required for good collaboration (shared cursors, shared selections, etc.). This can be very hard to implement on top of a DOM syncing approach from outside of the engine itself. Unfortunately, without these features, the collaborative editing experience is not that great.

There are several projects out there that are attempting to remedy this situation. The folks at CKEditor are working on CKEditor 5 which has collaboration in mind. Also, over at Convergence we are trying to work with the authors of many of the popular editors to enable real time collaboration.

The reality is that it is still a pretty new space and evolving quickly. There is no tested, scalable, slam dunk solution that provides and out of the box fully capable, collaborative, free and open source editor. The situation looks to be improving over 2018. Hopefully in the next 12-24 months this becomes a much easier problem.